# Java Reflection/Generic Types for dynamic-like type casting

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am wondering if this is possible. I am creating a class that holds a `Number` and that number can be a `Float` or an `Integer.` However, at runtime, that is decided.

I want to make a more elegant function that can take either the Float or Integer and do math on it, and since I do store the type of variable it is in an enum, I am hoping I can accomplish this using generics/reflection.

Here is my enum

```
public enum Type {

    FLOAT,
    INTEGER;

    public final Class clazz;

    Type() {
        if (this.name().equals("FLOAT"))
            clazz = Float.class;
        else if (this.name().equals("INTEGER"))
            clazz = Integer.class;
        else
            clazz = null;
    }
}
```

It is internal to my class.

Here is some code:

```
private <T extends Number> T compareTo(Class<T> lhs, Class<T> rhs) {
    // lhs > rhs return 1
    // rhs < lhs return -1
    // else return 0
}
```

Now, as we know with Java, your can't dynamically type casts like `type.clazz lhzType = (type.clazz) lhs` but is there any way using proper generics to get this done? I feel like there ought to be since if any reflection issues come up, it can just be thrown as an error. But I'm not mega advanced with Java as of now.

Comment: I am not sure what are you really trying to do (what is your idea for  comparing Classes, I understand comparing objects of classes but comparing Types) but it seems that you can improve a little your enum by using http://pastebin.com/By5Kb1KV

Comment: I'm confused - why would `compareTo` take `Class<T>`s instead of `T`s?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but I can tell you how to implement the code fragments you have posted:

Firstly, your enum should pass the (bounded) class into the constructor:

```
public enum Type {

    FLOAT(Float.class),
    INTEGER(Integer.class);

    private final Class<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> clazz;

    Type(Class<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Note that I don't know what you're going to *do* with that class.

Secondly, your method needs to *type* the method to declare the type of the objects passed in, *and* you don't need to refer to a class type of your enum, and the method doesn't really have anything to do with the enum either. It can be a static utility method put anywhere:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> int compareTo(T lhs, T rhs) {
    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
}
```

The key here is the bound to both `Number` and `Comparable<T>`, because while all `Number` subclasses implement `compareTo()`, the `Number` class does *not* define it.

---

To *return* a type the same as the parameters, you can use reflection, something like this:

```
// Coded for brevity rather than "best practice"
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> T compareTo(Class<T> clazz, T lhs, T rhs) throws Exception {   
    String s = "some string that represents the value of the new Numner";
    T t = clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(s);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Okay but there was one other thing. If I want to create a new number, say a Float, that is based on the Type in the enum, how could I declare it?

I sort of alluded to this issue in the last paragraph but I should have also made it a main point in my question.

Comment: Basically, I think your enum should be the *operations*, not the *type*. It's quite unusual to declare types like this. Perhaps you should show some code in your question of how you'd like to *use* your enum - even if the code doesn't compile - so we can understand the intent of your idea.

Comment: See edited answer for one possible implementation that returns a type. The `clazz` may be the clazz in your enum rather tan pass it in.